# how to create expire link in c# link expire after 5 hours

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

I have web service the webservice save image file in server. I send this image link to our customer,like www.abc.com/image.jpg. I want to expire the link after 5 hours, but the image are still in same location, how do this?

```
public string UploadFile(byte[] f, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        string Paths = "~/DispatchDriverImages/" + fileName;
        if(File.Exists(Paths))
        {
            File.Delete(Paths);
        }
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(f);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath
                    ("~/DispatchDriverImages/") + fileName, FileMode.Create);

        ms.WriteTo(fs);

        ms.Close();
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();

        return "OK";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the file location and its expiration date (or creation date) somewhere like a database for example. Then you can have a worker (e.g. a console application) which goes to the database and deletes the files expired.

Comment: i want link expire not delete image.. ;(

Comment: Then add a flag to your database showing whether a file is expired or not. Check this flag when serving the file to the user.

Comment: Is a valid answer, I have used this principle